# SQLite3 - Location of db

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I have implemented SQLite3 into my discord bot, everything seems to work and I can commit rows to my db, do a select and retrieve them, however in my local directory for the project I can't see the DB itself.

I've tried looking for commands to log the location to my log file but nothing seems to work either.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

This is my function at present:

```
def add_replay_to_db(filename: str, gamejson: str, playerjson: str, resultjson: str, replaysource: str, messageauthor: str, md5: str):
    try:
        db_path = '/database/yesman.db'

        # Ensure the directory exists
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(db_path)):
            fullpath = os.path.dirname(db_path)
            os.makedirs(fullpath)
            logger.info(f'Database created: {fullpath}')


        logger.info(f'Adding {filename} to the SQL database')

        connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS replay_raw_data (
                            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            filename TEXT,
                            game_json TEXT,
                            player_json TEXT,
                            result_json TEXT,
                            replay_source TEXT,
                            user TEXT,
                            md5 TEXT
                          )''')

        # INSERT INTO
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO replay_raw_data (filename, game_json, player_json, result_json, replay_source, user, md5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                       (str(filename), str(gamejson), str(playerjson), str(resultjson), str(replaysource), str(messageauthor), str(md5)))

        connection.commit()

        # Fetch and print data
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM replay_raw_data')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)

    except sqlite3.Error as er:
            logger.error(f'{er}')

    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
```

Comment: Did you check `/database/yesman.db`?

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong place, either you are not going to the absolute path `/database/yesman.db`, or you have a docker volume or something (if you are using docker)

Comment: @TerenceSimpson
Hi both, it is most certainly not in that location.

Have updated the above with a screenie. Also can confirm using the row print() that data exists - somewhere.

Comment: If you are using WSL, then it's possible that the file is at the root of that.

Comment: There is no file called "yesman.db" in any of the project folders, this is what is matching me scratch my head.

Comment: Ended up downloading "Everything" and searched my PC, appears to have put the database into my C:\database' directory. Very odd.

Comment: So it was where we said. `/` means the root folder, and that's where you found it

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2:

I installed "Everything" to search for the file, turned out setting

`db_path = '/database/yesman.db'`

Installed the file to my root C:\database directorty. I changed this to

`db_path = './database/yesman.db'`

and it recreate the database in the correct project location.